# Spring JPA @Query with LIKE

Tags: java, jquery, sql, spring, jpa

I'm trying to make a method in CrudRepository that will be able to give me list of users, whose usernames are LIKE the input parameter(not only begin with, but also contains it). I tried to use method `"findUserByUsernameLike(@Param("username") String username)"` but as it is told in Spring documentation, this method is equal to 
"`where user.username like ?1`". It is not good for me, as I already told that I'm trying to get all users whose username contains ...

I wrote a queryto the method but it even doesn't deploy.

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

@Query("select u from user u where u.username like '%username%'")
List<User> findUserByUsernameLike(@Param("username") String username);
}
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: You might want to use `containing` in order to benefits from indexes, see http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/repository-query-keywords.html

Answer (score 240, accepted):

Try to use the following approach (it works for me):

```
@Query("SELECT u.username FROM User u WHERE u.username LIKE CONCAT('%',:username,'%')")
List<String> findUsersWithPartOfName(@Param("username") String username);
```

Notice: The table name in JPQL must start with a capital letter.

Comment: or `WHERE UPPER(u.username) LIKE CONCAT('%',UPPER(:username),'%')` to do a case-insensitive search

Comment: SQL-Injection using your solution possible? (asking because of CONCAT)

Comment: @ramden all `@Param`s are sanitized, so no.

Comment: You can just do like :username and then .setParameter("username", "%foo%");

Comment: how to set .setParameter("username", "%foo%"); @MatthewDaumen

Comment: This helped me at work. Thank you for this solution

Comment: @BradMace, or even `WHERE UPPER(u.username) LIKE CONCAT('%',UPPER(TRIM((:username)),'%')` to clear off blank space that could come from a Ctrl+V sometimes

Answer (score 151):

> Using [Query creation from method names](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation), check table 4 where they explain some keywords.

1. Using Like: `select ... like :username`

   ```
    List<User> findByUsernameLike(String username);
   ```
2. StartingWith: `select ... like :username%`

   ```
    List<User> findByUsernameStartingWith(String username);
   ```
3. EndingWith: `select ... like %:username`

   ```
    List<User> findByUsernameEndingWith(String username);
   ```
4. Containing: `select ... like %:username%`

   ```
    List<User> findByUsernameContaining(String username);
   ```

Notice that the answer that you are looking for is **number 4**. You don't have to use @Query

Comment: That's really helpful, but if I want to use the Containing keyword, can I also make it case-insensitive? In the documentation there's something said about StringMatcher. It seems if I created a separate function with ExampleMatcher it would work, but can I somehow declare it in the method name not to write my own function just for adding this case-insensitivity?

Comment: Just wanted to add that you can also ignore case, if needed, like this:    `List<User> findByUsernameContainingIgnoreCase(String username);`

Comment: The percent symbol should be inverted `StartingWith: select ... like :username%` and `EndingWith: select ... like %:username` ... anyway great answer... should be the accepted one. Thanks.

Comment: @Robert i have a column data with uppercase and i used JPQL like method and passed lower case value and able to get the values. without IgnoreCase also it is fetching the improper cases data. Why this weird behavior is happened?

Comment: @greenhorn Please open a seperate StackOverflow question and add some example of your data in the table and what you are querying for.

Answer (score 32):

Another way: instead `CONCAT` function we can use double pipe: **:lastname || '%'**

```
@Query("select c from Customer c where c.lastName LIKE :lastname||'%'")
List<Customer> findCustomByLastName( @Param("lastname") String lastName);
```

You can put anywhere, prefix, suffix or both

```
:lastname ||'%'  
'%' || :lastname  
'%' || :lastname || '%'
```

Answer (score 13):

Easy to use following (no need use CONCAT or ||):

```
@Query("from Service s where s.category.typeAsString like :parent%")
List<Service> findAll(@Param("parent") String parent);
```

Documented in: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html.

Comment: there is no need to add "SELECT s" ? can we start directly from "FROM"?

Comment: Yes, it's not mandatory for functionality, but some spelling checkers show error.

Answer (score 10):

`List<User> findByUsernameContainingIgnoreCase(String username);`

in order to ignore case issues

Comment: SQL-Injection using your solution possible?

Comment: @xuezhongyu01 you think Spring Data JPA allows SQL injection in their derived queries? The parameters get sanitized, of course.

Answer (score 3):

This way works for me, (using Spring Boot version 2.0.1. RELEASE):

```
@Query("SELECT u.username FROM User u WHERE u.username LIKE %?1%")
List<String> findUsersWithPartOfName(@Param("username") String username);
```

Explaining: The ?1, ?2, ?3 etc. are place holders the first, second, third parameters, etc. In this case is enough to have the parameter is surrounded by % as if it was a standard SQL query but without the single quotes.

Comment: @Ralph, I'm trying to achieve this using your way, but always getting a list with 0 objects while I'm supposed to get a list containing 2 objects, would you please suggest anything regarding this? 

following is the question regarding this 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65085720/how-to-convert-like-searchkey-to-native-query-in-spring-boot-jpa

Comment: @Ralph could you please explain why named parameters are better in this case ?

Comment: @hakima maarouf: I thougt support for positional paramerters was removed in Hibernate 5.3 - but this is not 100% correct, they removed only HQL-style positional parameters (just `?`) but not the JPA Style positional parameters `?1` (https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12101) - so you can use it - but I still recommend to use named parameters for better readability

Answer (score 3):

this `@Query("select u from user u where u.username like '%:username%'")` does not work in some cases!

working solution for me was

```java
@Query("SELECT u.username FROM User u WHERE u.username LIKE CONCAT('%',:username,'%')")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Spring-Data-Jpa +2.7 there is a bug with LIKE parameter using %:param% in queries. It will be fixed in version 3.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2548

Answer (score 1):

You Missed a colon(:) before the username parameter. therefore your code must change from:

```
@Query("select u from user u where u.username like '%username%'")
```

to :

```
@Query("select u from user u where u.username like '%:username%'")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query("select u from user u where u.username LIKE :username")
List<User> findUserByUsernameLike(@Param("username") String username);
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem of deplouing was that jpql is case sensitive, now it is deploying, but 'LIKE' does not work as I want. It finds just records that are equal to input parameter completely(not containing it).

Answer (score 0):

List findUsersContaining(String username);

I tried this. It works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As answered [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21461715/9473287), `LIKE CONCAT('%',:username,'%')` worked for me, also if you don't want to use sql `CONCAT`, you can do the following in you code:

```
String username = "%"+ inputUsername + "%";
```

and pass the value to the query

```
@Query("SELECT u.username FROM User u WHERE u.username LIKE :username")
List<String> findUsersWithPartOfName(@Param("username") String username);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@Query("select b.equipSealRegisterId from EquipSealRegister b where b.sealName like %?1% and b.deleteFlag = '0'" )
    List<String>findBySeal(String sealname);
```

I have tried this code and it works.