# Issues using % in hql query

Tags: java, spring, repository, hql, spring-data-jpa

I want to search the list of employees by login and I use a DAO interface that extends `JpaRepository`:

```
public interface EmployeRepository  extends  JpaRepository<Employe, Long> {
    @Query("select e from Employe e where e.login like :x")
    public Page<Employe> employeeParLogin(@Param("x")String login, Pageable p);
}
```

In my service layer, I invoke this method with

```
@Override
public Page<Employe> employeeParLogin(String login, Pageable p) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return employeRepository.findByLogin("%"+login+"%", p);
}
```

When I test it with

```
Page<Employe> pe = employeMetier.employeeParLogin("fe",new PageRequest(0,2));
```

it does not return anything although I have an employee who has a login containing `fe`.

P.S.: It only works fine when I remove the two `%` of the parameter login in the method of the service layer and I write the whole login.

Comment: you can check this [Spring JPA @Query with LIKE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21456494/spring-jpa-query-with-like) as this QA provide two way either you can use **CONCAT function** or you can use **double pipe**

Answer (score 0):

you can check this [Spring JPA @Query with LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21456494/spring-jpa-query-with-like) as this QA provide two way either you can use CONCAT function or you can use double pipe.

So your **EmployeRepository** interface will be like this :

```
   public interface EmployeRepository  extends  JpaRepository<Employe, Long> {
      // you can use concat function like : CONCAT('%',:x,'%') or double pipe || 
      @Query("select e from Employe e where e.login like '%'||:x||'%'")
      public Page<Employe> employeeParLogin(@Param("x")String login, Pageable p);
   }
```

And for your service layer it will be :

```
@Override
public Page<Employe> employeeParLogin(String login, Pageable p) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return employeRepository.findByLogin(login, p);
}
```

---

Otherwise if none of this work you can remove the @Query line and rename your method `employeeParLogin` to `findByLoginContaining`, so it will be :

`public Page<Employe> findByLoginContaining(String login, Pageable p);`

Hope that it will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried this solution but it worked only when I put in parameter the whole login and not a part of it. I did not understand what you mean by double pipe??

Comment: From the provided QA, there is an example :  
`@Query("select e from Employe e where e.login like '%'|| :x || '%'") 
    public Page<Employe> employeeParLogin(@Param("x")String login, Pageable p);` , and no need to use **"%"+login+"%"** in `employeRepository.findByLogin` method

Comment: It remains the same problem. It works only with the whole login :(

Comment: ok all i have done is I have changed the query in method of the repository this way @Query("select e from Employe e where e.login like '%'|| :x || '%'") and i remove the '%' from the method of the service layer. when I test it it worked only when the parameter login=imene for example as I have in my database already a login=imene but not with i im or imen. I hope I have explained clearly :)

Comment: please check my update, as you can use CONCAT('%',:x,'%') instead of double pipe

Comment: i am sorry if I have bothered you but it still works only when the parameter is equal to a login in the database and not when it is equal to part of it.

Comment: No it's okay, in **EmployeRepository** can you remove the @Query line and rename your method  `employeeParLogin` to `findByLoginContaining`, so it will be : ` public Page<Employe> findByLoginContaining(String login, Pageable p);`

Comment: I have done like you said and it is always the same problem

Comment: Did you try @Query("select e from Employe e where e.login like %:x%")? Note: This param is without concat or single quote.

Comment: heloo Abel, I just want to tell you that it worked strangely. All I have done is I have copied the query from an old project and I edited it of course. So this is the method in  my repository  @Query("select e from Employe e where e.login like :x ")
 public List<Employe> EmployeParLogin(@Param("x")String login) and I invoke it with the following method in the service layer @Override public Page<Employe> empLoyerParLogin(String login, Pageable p) { return EmployeParLogin("%"+login+"%", p); } It is weird as I have not change anything but it worked.

Comment: Congratulation @FerdaousBenSalha ^^ , By the way it's not weird as it work now, you have remove the parameter **Pageable** from your method `EmployeRepository.employeeParLogin`

Comment: ohh I test it with this  method and then with second who has the parameter pageable and it worked but I did not notice that I put the first one in the comment. Anyway thank you :)