# Spring data repository how to query ElementCollection of String containing substring

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity with an `@ElementCollection` of strings:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<String> names;
```

While it is no problem to query by names:

```
List<MyEntity> findByNames(String name);
```

It seems not to work if i try to create a method with "contains". I want to find entities that have a matching name that contains given substring:

```
List<MyEntity> findByNamesContains(String substringOfname);
```

This yields no results but also no error. It seems that the "contains" keyword here is interpreted as the list of name should contain. If i change it to

```
List<MyEntity> findByNamesContains(List<String> substringOfname);
```

This methods works.

My question is: is there a combination of keywords to get a method that returns all entities that have a name matching a given substring?

If not how would a JPQL query look like?

Answer (score 2):

As far I knew, No you can't do it wit Spring-JPA-Date repository method names, but it's very easy to be done with `JPQL` and Spring repository

here's **JPQL**

`select e from MyEntity e join e.names name where name LIKE CONCAT('%', :name, '%')`

for **case-insensitive** query use this

`select e from MyEntity e join e.names name where LOWER(name) LIKE CONCAT('%', LOWER(:name), '%')`

**JPQL** + Spring **repository**

```
@Query("select e from MyEntity e join e.names name where name LIKE CONCAT('%', :name, '%') ")
List<MyEntity> findByName(@Param("name") String name);
```

for more information use look [here](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/string) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21456494/spring-jpa-query-with-like), Hope this help (:

Answer (score 0):

In case of single string use **containing** keyword. Works in the same way as "like" in sql queries.

Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#_supported_query_keywords

Comment: Containing has the same meaning as contains and thus is not working here. it matches if list of names contains given name but not if some name contains given substring

Comment: Did you write findByNameContaining or findByNamesContaining ? I meant the first.

Comment: it only works with "names" it must match the name of the field and this is "names". Using "name" will yield an error: "no propertiy found name .. did you mean names?"