# Is there a query that returns table content with partial information in the search box? [for @Query annotation]

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpql

This is my query

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE first_name =?1", nativeQuery = true)
public List<Student> searchStudents(String searchName);
```

So now when I search a  student I need to give the full first name or else it returns null... Here is my Student service.. basically returning a list, and this is the method I call in my UIController..

```
    return studentRepository.searchStudents(searchName);
```

If there is not a statement in the @Query annotation, how can I search with just a few letters of the word and get words containing those letters?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the LIKE operator ([see doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9/functions-matching.html))

Using Spring JPA you can do this using the method signature:

```
List<Student> findByFirstnameLike(String name);
```

More details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38115592/4325878