# @Query not accepting LIKE to perform fine grain search

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

1. When I run this I am able to get the result, but only when I type the full name..
2. `@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE first_name=?1", nativeQuery = true)
   public List<Student> findByFirstNameLike(String searchName);`
3. Now I tried to add like operator
4. `@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE first_name like=?1", nativeQuery = true)
   public List<Student> findByFirstNameLike(String searchName);
   }`
5. I look for student Daniel by typing in Dan and hit search and this is the exception
6. `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '='Dan'' at line 1`
7. I even tried changing the = to a % like this..
8. `WHERE first_name like%?1`
9. point 2 works, but points 4 and 6 give me SQLSyntaxErrorException, how do I resolve this? thanks
10. I have also tried using @Param annotation as mentioned in this link and still get syntax exception https://stackoverflow.com/a/38115592/4325878

Answer (score 3):

This query is wrong:

```
"SELECT * FROM Student WHERE first_name like=?1"
```

you can't place equals sign after `like` keyword. It should be like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM Student WHERE first_name like ?1"
```

If you place `"%"`, then it should be a part of parameter.

Also take a look at this:

```
public List<Student> findByFirstNameLike(String searchName);
```

parentheses are not balanced. For the future, please, provide compliant code snippets...

Answer (score 0):

You should try like below i posted,It will help you i hope...

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE first_name= :searchName%", nativeQuery = true)
public List<Student> findByFirstNameLike(String searchName);
```