# how to convert like %searchKey% to native query in spring boot jpa

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, nativequery

I'm trying to convert the following query to native query, I'm getting empty list while the query is returning 2 tuples

following is the query :

```
SELECT 
  s.id AS shopID,
  s.shop_name AS shopName 
FROM
  shop s 
WHERE s.shop_name LIKE '%store%' ;
```

following is the method I've created which is returning empty list while it's supposed to send a list containing two objects
(this is the method of m repository)

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT \n" +
            "  s.id AS shopID,\n" +
            "  s.shop_name AS shopName \n" +
            "FROM\n" +
            "  shop s \n" +
            "WHERE s.shop_name LIKE %:searchKey%", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Object[]> buyerDashboardSearchSuggestion(@Param("searchKey") String searchKey);
```

result of query
[image]

following is my postman request

```
{
    "searchKey": "store"
}
```

dependencies are related to db are

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.21</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: You are missing single quotes around LIKE and around percentage sign.

Comment: would it be like 
"WHERE s.shop_name 'LIKE' '%:searchKey%' " ??

Comment: I tried with this             "WHERE s.shop_name LIKE '%:searchKey%'"

and still getting a list of 0 object

Comment: That should have worked. Review your parameters, is it case sensitive?

Comment: yes, but even though i maintain case, like "Store", then also I'm getting empty list.

Comment: I'm using spring boot 2.3.3

Comment: Can you create a projection interface and use that in List instead of Object[]?

Comment: I am not allowed to do that since I've been specifically asked to follow this convention

Comment: There is one thing that could cause the problem: the combination of native query with an like expression without quotes, but this is just the first point I would try to debug. (Debug by logging the executed sql query and the execute this query with our preferred SQL-Tool)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the combination of `%:searchKey%` in a native query, I think `%` must be part of the parameter.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT \n" +
            "  s.id AS shopID,\n" +
            "  s.shop_name AS shopName \n" +
            "FROM\n" +
            "  shop s \n" +
            "WHERE s.shop_name LIKE :searchKey", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object[]> buyerDashboardSearchSuggestion_internal(@Param("searchKey") String searchKey);

default List<Object[]> buyerDashboardSearchSuggestion(String searchKey) {
    return buyerDashboardSearchSuggestion_internal("%"+searchKey+"%");
    //todo escape special chars like % and _ in "searchKey"
}
```