# Native query with named parameter in "LIKE"

Tags: java, nativequery, hibernate-native-query

I want to use named parameters in native query. It works fine in cases like this:

```
and p.department_id in :myDepthsIds 
...
query.setParameter("myDepthsIds", myDepthsIds);
```

However, I want to use named parameter in "LIKE" part of query, and if I try

```
stringQuery = stringQuery + " and upper(p.name) like upper('%:searchString%')";
...
query.setParameter("searchString", searchString);
```

it gives me

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown parameter name : searchString

So, what is a right way to use named parameters in "LIKE", "LIKE UPPER" etc?

Comment: Problem is solved by help of this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21456494/spring-jpa-query-with-like

Comment: When you use `'%:searchString%'`, that means a literal string with the string value `%:searchString%`. What you want would be `'%' || :searchString || '%'` (assuming standard SQL syntax)